# How to build Xamarin.Mac application from command line or build script

Tags: xamarin, rake, teamcity, xamarin.mac

We have a Xamarin.Mac application that is ready to be Continuously Integrated via TeamCity.

We have a build host on Mac machine where Xamarin Studio is installed. The next step is to create a build step in a build configuration.

Unlike VS, Xamarin Studio doesn't seem to have a Xamarin.Studio runner for TeamCity. Thus as articles on Xamarin Wiki recommend, one should use build scripts, like Rake.

I, being a .Net dev, has spent a day learning Rake and I unfortunately don't like it.

Another thing is I don't know which command would build my .sln file given that I reuse some of the Rakefile's I've found online. Please tell me what is the command to build .sln in Xamarin Studio for Mac.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using Jenkins with a bash script but the command we call is [mdtool](http://www.makelinux.com/man/1/M/mdtool) like so

```
/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build -p:"PROJECT_NAME" -t:Build -c:"RELEASE_TYPE" "SOULTIONFILE.sln"
```

Just seen [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5468/automating-build) too on the Xamarin forums about Mac build automation

Answer (score 2):

Here is a command which works for me

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:"MySolution_MyMacProject" /p:Configuration="Release"
```

Keep in mind that you need replace some specific characters like **.** in the target or configuration names with the **_** as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019)

Comment: What is /t here

Comment: /t stands for target which is your project inside solution

Comment: When you do this do you have to do any signing yourself? Also, what file do you actually distribute to your team as a result of the build? I have the same need as the OP of TeamCity Xamarin.Mac build. I need this for QA testing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @spaceagestereo presuming your app builds you will get a valid Mac app which you have to sign yourself via [xcrun altool](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/altool.1.html). For your specific case you probably want to notarize the app, pack into dmg, notarize it as well and then distribute it as a usual drag and drop macOs installer.